# Highslide Full Size Image icon not working with controls

Tags: highslide

I'm trying to use this example of Highslide with controls:

http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/gallery-custom-nav.html

It works fine, but when I use it, I lose the 'Full Size Image' option. The icon doesn't show up.

I've been using Highslide for a while, only without controls, and used to get that option naturally.

fullExpandOpacity is set to 1.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Highslide galleries with controls doesn’t have the type of full-expand button you are looking for (the full-expand button you are used to from images without controls).

The demo you’ve found is something I created for a customer a long time ago, and he only wanted the next/previous buttons. The buttons are built using the JavaScript for our regular controls, but the image for this custom-made control contains only next/previous buttons - not the move/close/full-expand buttons.

You can either create a new image that also contains the full-expand button and change the CSS for the controls to reflect the new part of the image (the full-expand button), or you can use one of our pre-made controls that has full set of buttons – see our demo galleries: http://highslide.com/index.htm => With Gallery, or create your own custom gallery with controls in the [Highslide Editor](http://highslide.com/editor/).

Comment: I got it.

Just one last question - I don't know JavaScript so it could be very dumb, sorry about that.

Using that example, I can see that when I press F, the picture get expanded.

Is there a way that I can join the F action with the showing up of the expand image icon?

Comment: Pressing the f key will always expand the image to its full size (if the image isn’t already shown in its full size). The full-expand icon you are used to (screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/GPOoxh5QPEI) isn’t available when you are using the `hs.addSlideshow` code that is necessary for the controls you are using now.